# Update Vue after an outside Ajax call

Tags: vue.js

I'm discovering Vuejs and I am trying to update the current data with an Ajax call with no success.

HTML:

```
<div id ="app">
    {{first_name}} {{last_name}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var my_data = {first_name : 'foo', last_name:'bar'}

var vm = new Vue({
     el: "#app",
     data : my_data
     })
```

I would like to make a refresh with an Ajax call triggered by a button:

```
 $(".myButton").click(function(){
      $.getJSON('/data').done(function(json){var my_data = json})
 })
```

In console, my_data displays new values but with no effect on HTML.

Comment: Vue doesn't detect changes on variables defined outside its data section, its the best when starting with vue, to go vue all the way to discovered the framework

Comment: I tried updating `vm.data` too but with no success

Comment: Because the way vue works, you need to update "vm.first_name" and vm.last_name"

Comment: If you want an answer of what's going wrong, you probably need to paste more code. However, if you need jQuery you are probably not using Vue optimally. Watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPUdtEf3oXI&t=8s. And check out axios library for data calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using a jQuery click handler, but that wasn't your question.

This:

```
{var my_data = json}
```

is simply assignment to a local variable. Its life is entirely within those curly braces, so you've accomplished nothing there. You are trying to replace the entire data item in your Vue, which can't be done with a simple assignment. You can copy the pieces, though:

```
{
    for (const key of Object.keys(json)) {
        vm[key] = json[key];
    }
}
```

Assuming `vm` is in scope where you set up the jQuery click handler, that should work for you. If your `var my_data` is also in scope, you could do it using that, as well:

```
{ Object.assign(my_data, json) }
```

Note how I have not made `my_data` a local variable. You cannot just assign to `my_data`, though, as that would replace the object, so it would no longer refer to `vm`'s `data`.